# Reading Yamldotnet with c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, yaml, yamldotnet

i've some problems when i'm trying to read a Yaml file using c# and need help to finish this task , how can i read a such Yaml file into variables so i can treat them .

```
FileConfig: 
  sourceFolder: /home
  destinationFolder: /home/billy/my-test-case
  scenarios: 
  - name: first-scenario 
    alterations: 
    - tableExtension: ln
      alterations: 
      - type: copy-line
        sourceLineIndex: 0
        destinationLineIndex: 0
      - type: cell-change
        sourceLineIndex: 0
        columnName: FAKE_COL
        newValue: NEW_Value1
    - tableExtension: env
      alterations: 
      - type: cell-change
        sourceLineIndex: 0
        columnName: ID
        newValue: 10
```

Here is my code

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"test.yaml");

var deserializer = new Deserializer();
var result = deserializer.Deserialize<List<Hashtable>>(new StringReader(text));
/*foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Item:");
    Console.WriteLine(item.GetType());
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("- {0} = {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
}    */
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It sounds like you've made a start - so please show us your existing code, and what problems you're seeing with it.

Comment: @JonSkeet
I've found this code using hashtable and DictionnaryEntry it can solve a problem of just a Lists .
but in my case i tried to found a good documentation to simplify that but didn't find

Comment: The Yaml Dotnet wiki has all the information you need, including samples showing how to deserialize. https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/wiki/Samples.DeserializeObjectGraph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a C# model of your document. Then you are able to use the `Deserializer` to fill that model with the data present into the document. A possible model for your document would be:

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    [YamlMember(Alias = "FileConfig", ApplyNamingConventions = false)]
    public FileConfig FileConfig { get; set; }
}

public class FileConfig
{
    public string SourceFolder { get; set; }
    public string DestinationFolder { get; set; }
    public List<Scenario> Scenarios { get; set; }
}

public class Scenario
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Alteration> Alterations { get; set; }
}

public class Alteration
{
    public string TableExtension { get; set; }
    public List<TableAlteration> Alterations { get; set; }  
}

public class TableAlteration
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int SourceLineIndex { get; set; }
    public int DestinationLineIndex { get; set; }
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string NewValue { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize to that model as follows:

```cs
var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder()
    .WithNamingConvention(CamelCaseNamingConvention.Instance)
    .Build();

var obj = deserializer.Deserialize<MyModel>(yaml);
```

You can run this code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SRABFM

Of course, the model that I suggest here is very naive and with more knowledge about your domain model, you will certainly be able to come up with a better one.